# How to decrease horizontal and vertical space between figures?

Tags: floats, minipage

I want to insert 24 figures each two of them side by side. I'm doing this through `\minipage` but I'm not satisfied with the result because although figures appear small but I can have just 4 of them in a page which occupies a lot of space . I'm repeating this part for each two of them , I get output but not a nice one , I would like to decrease the horizontal and vertical space between them . I would appreciate any advice .

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
     \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
     \usepackage{graphicx}
     \usepackage{subcaption}
     \usepackage{floats}

     \begin{document}
     \begin{figure}[h!]  
     \centering
     \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
       \captionsetup{type=figure}
       \centering
       \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/22.pdf}
     \end{minipage}
     \begin{minipage}{.45\textwidth}
       \captionsetup{type=figure}
        \centering
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{figures/T22.pdf}
      \end{minipage}
       \caption*{$H=1$}
      \end{figure}
      \end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a full [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Comment: @Aradnix thank you. I compile all other chapters together , this particular chapter doesn't have \begin and \end. I use in preamble \usepackage{caption}, \usepackage{subcaption} , \usepackage{floats} ,\usepackage{graphicx}

Comment: Well if you read the links above you'll see that here are in the habit of accompanying questions with a minimal example that is functional, i.e., we can easily copy and paste to easily detect errors. It is not an imposition, it's just a healthy tradition that helps us to provide aid. And you shouldn't put all the document, just assemble a minimal but illustrative example.

Comment: @Aradnix I've edited the question. I hope it's useful now :)

Answer (score 4):

The `minipage` in your example are not doing anything useful, and it seems you don't want floating figuures either so I'd not use `figure`. If you need captions `caption` package provides `\captionof{figure}{...}` but to put 24 images close together you can use

```
{\centering
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig01}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig02}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig03}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig04}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig05}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig06}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig07}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig08}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig09}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig10}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig11}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig12}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig13}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig14}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig15}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig16}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig17}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig18}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig19}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig20}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig21}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig22}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig23}\linebreak[0]%
\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{fig24}\linebreak[0]%

}
```

which will make 6 rows of four with no horizontal space between them, and `\lineskip` glue between the rows. The image widths can of course be adjusted and/or space added
instead of the linebreak penalty.

Comment: thank you so much , so it I want 12 rows of two , I would change the width to `width=.5\textwidth` ?

Comment: @Singu `\includegraphics` has _no_ spacing rules, it is positioned like the letter `X`. As far as TeX is concerned the  above is just a paragraph with 24 big letters, with no space between them like `XXXXXXXX` (but with `\linebreak[0]` added to allow linebreaking). In practice you probably want a bit less than .5\textwidth to allow some space, and you might want to put a blank line (paragraph break) and some vertical space between each row, but the point is, you don't need to _decrease_ the space added, no space at all will be added unless you add it.

Comment: @Singu: Youi should take a look at the `floatrow` package, which is designed for that and works well with `caption`.

Comment: the output of this code is exactly the same as my output.

Comment: @Singu that seems unlikely, but since you have not produced a reproducible example file, it is impossible for anyone else to say.